# Proof that a topology = union of basis elements

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

Lemma 13.1 in Munkres states:

> Let $X$ be a set; let $\mathfrak{B}$ be a basis for a topology $\mathscr{T}$ on $X$. Then $\mathscr{T}$ equals the collection of all unions of elements of $\mathscr{B}$.

The first line of Munkres's proof is:

> Given a collection of elements of $\mathfrak{B}$, they are also elements of $\mathscr{T}$.

I'm having trouble understanding why this is true. Can someone point me in the right direction?

EDIT (Added the definition of a basis):

> If $X$ is a set, a basis for a topology on $X$ is a collection $\mathfrak{B}$ of subsets of $X$ (called basis elements) such that (1) For each $x \in X$, there is at least one basis element $B$ containing $x$; (2 )If $x$ belongs to the intersection of two basis elements $B_1$ and $B_2$, then there is a basis element $B_3$ containing $x$ such the $B_3 \subset B_1 \cap B_2$.

UPDATED attempt at proving this lemma:

> A set $U \subset X$ is open in the topology generated by $\mathscr{B}$ if for each $x \in U$, there exists $B \in \mathfrak{B}$ such that $x \in \mathfrak{B}$ such that $x \in B \subset U$. Given $B \in \mathfrak{B}$, for any $x \in B$, we have $x \in B \subset B$, so $B$ is open, so $\mathfrak{B} \subset \mathscr{T}$. As $\mathscr{T}$ is a topology, it is closed under unions, so $\bigcup\limits_{B \in \mathfrak{B}} B \in \mathcal{T}$. Conversely, let $U \in \mathscr{T}$. As $U$ is open, given $x \in U$, there exists $B \in \mathscr{B}$ such that $x \in B_x \subset U$. As $B_x \subset U$ for each $x \in U$, we have $\bigcup\limits_{x \in U} B_x \subset U$. As $x \in B_x \subset \bigcup\limits_{x \in U} B_x$ for each $x \in U$, we have $U \subset \bigcup\limits_{x \in U} B_x$. Therefore, $U = \bigcup\limits_{x \in U} B_x$, and $U$ is a union of elements of $B$.

Comment: Can you update your post with your definition of "a basis for a topology"?

Comment: @311411 Yes, I've added it.

Comment: Although you have you defined what "basis for a topology" means, despite its name, that definition does not explain how a "basis for a topology" gives rise to a topology. A common definition for that is "the smallest topology that contains the basis". (With that definition, the claim is of course trivial). So, what is, according to Munkres, the topology corresponding to a basis?

Comment: Sorry, the definition is: $U \subset X$ is open if for each $x \in U$, there exists $B \in \mathfrak{B}$ such that $x \in B \subset U$. I added an updated attempt at this lemma. Could you take a look at it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

Remember how Munkres defines the topology generated by $\mathcal{B}$. This should be on the page before the one you're reading:

> ... we define the **topology $\mathcal{T}$ generated by $\mathcal{B}$** as follows: A subset $U$ of $X$ is said to be open in $X$ (that is, an element of $\mathcal{T}$) if for every $x \in U$, there is a basis element $B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B$ and $B \subset U$. Note that each basis element is itself an element of $\mathcal{T}$.

It's exactly this "note" at the end that Munkres is referring to in your question. Since if $B \in \mathcal{B}$, then obviously for each $x \in B$ there is a basis element $B$ with $x \in B$ and $B \subset B$! $B$ itself works! So $B$ is in the topology we generate. In particular, given a basis $\mathcal{B}$, every element of $\mathcal{B}$ ends up being open in the topology it generates.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you for this. I added an updated attempt at my understanding of proving this lemma. Could you tell me whether I have the correct idea?